# adapter java class is not recognizing the layout files in android

Tags: android, layout

I am developing a movie player application in android. My adapter java class is not recognizing the layout files. All the R.id/R.layout syntax are throwing errors.

```
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_item, null); 

        movie_item can not be resolved or is not a field. (movie_item is a layout)

ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        thumbnail can not be resolved or is not a field. (thumbnail is an image view in movie_item layout)
```

My .xml files dont have any error. 
My adapter class imported android.r previously. I removed it and cleaned the project. It still shows the same error.

Comment: import yourPackageName.R class... and be sure you have xml layout with the name `movie_item`

Comment: resolved.. thanks a lot Gopal  :)

Comment: @GopalRao: if it's an answer, please post it as one. :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy let the comment to be a comment... thanks

Answer (score 0):

import yourPackageName.R class... and be sure you have xml layout with the name movie_item